# Why do I need to explicitly type my method arguments when implementing an interface?

Tags: typescript

For example:

```
interface Foo {
  someProperty: Number
  someMethod?: (str: string) => void
}

class Bar implements Foo {
  someProperty = 42
  someMethod (str) {
    console.log(this.someProperty)
  }
}
```

The `str` parameter to `someMethod()` is obviously a string. But the compiler complains:

```
test.tsx(8,15): error TS7006: Parameter 'str' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: `tsc --version` reports version 2.8.3.

Comment: Aside: Always use `number`, not `Number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Nothing. Its not supported in TypeScript [as mentioned here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1373).

## Fix

Provide an explicit annotation in the class.

Comment: basarat better at finding github issues than I am :(

Answer (score 2):

> The str parameter to someMethod() is obviously a string

Not necessarily. You could have written a number of different signatures that satisfied the interface; for example

```
    someMethod (s: string | number) {
```

or

```
    someMethod (s: any) {
```

The `implements` clause is only a *post hoc* check on your class that makes sure your class successfully implemented the interface. It does *not* directly change the types of any declared properties or methods in your class.

Because you'd have an implicit `any` if you *didn't* have the `implements` clause, you have an implicit `any` *with* it, because `implements` clauses don't affect the types of the class members.

Answer (score 1):

Classes are not the only way to implement interfaces. You don't have to type method arguments explicitly if you use a function that creates and returns an object (sometimes called factory function) instead of a class:

```
interface Foo {
  someProperty: number
  someMethod?: (str: string) => void
}

function createBar(): Foo {
    return {
        someProperty: 42,
        someMethod: (str) => {
            const n = str.length; // ok because parameter inferred as  str: string
        }
    }
}
```